# Should I declare the usage of a new template.php file?

Tags: 8, theming

I created a *template.php* file, put the following function inside, saved, and flushed all Drupal cache. The desired change didn't occur.

```php
function garku_process_html(&$variables) {
  $variables['styles'] = preg_replace('/.css\?.*"/','.css"', $variables['styles']);
}
```

How should I declare the usage of a new template.php file in a Drupal 8 sub-theme?

I ask since I haven't found anything about this in the documentation, for example in [Overview of theme files](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/overview-of-theme-files).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Drupal 8 themes don't have template.php files. Now they use a *mytheme.theme* file, which needs to be located inside the directory containing the theme. (Replace *mytheme* with the machine name used by the theme.)

[Preprocessing and modifying attributes in a .theme file](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/modifying-attributes-in-a-theme-file) shows an example of preprocess function, which is placed in the *mytheme.theme* file, instead of the *template.php* file.

Answer (score 3):

The file name was changed to [theme-name].theme; from [the docs](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/drupal-8-theme-folder-structure):

> ***.theme**
>
> The .theme file is a PHP file that contains all the conditional logic and data (pre)processing of the output. It may also extend basic theme settings.